# Installing Django-tailwindCSSS fails on tailwind strart

Tags: django, npm, tailwind-css

I'm installing Django-Tailwind following the instructions:
https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
The Django part works but the part that updates the CSS by runniong the command"
"python manage.py tailwind start" fails.
the node that executed the command in, package.json,

### "dev": "tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w", fails with a message that ends with: "Object.loadConfig (D:\DjangoTailwind__Starter\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\bu il\plugin.js:135:49) {'code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ 'D:\DjangoTailwind__Starter\src\djtailwind\theme\static_src\tailwind.config.js ']} I tried running: "npm install -D tailwindcss" but without success I' using Windowes 11 Node version 21.5.0

Answer (score 0):

To fix the MODULE_NOT_FOUND issue you're getting when using the command python manage.py tailwind start in your Django-Tailwind project on Windows 11 with Node version 21.5.0, let's take a step-by-step approach. This issue often occurs when the Node.js environment is unable to discover a module required by your tailwind.config.js file or another component of your setup. Here's a step-by-step guide to identifying and resolving this problem:

1. Confirm the path to tailwind.config.js.
   First, make sure the path of your tailwind.config.js specified in the error message truly refers to the file's location in your project. If there is a discrepancy, you must update the path in your package.json or wherever it is referenced.
2. Clean and reinstall Node modules.
   Delete node_modules and package_lock.json: This step deletes any corrupted or incomplete module installs.
   Re-install dependencies. Run npm install from the project directory. This guarantees that all dependencies, including Tailwind CSS, are neatly installed.
3. Verify Tailwind CSS installation.
   Ensure that Tailwind CSS is properly installed and mentioned under devDependencies in your package.json. If it is missing, reinstall it using npm install -D tailwindcss and look for any issues along the process.
4. Check for typos in configuration.
   Check the file names and directories in your tailwind.config.js and package.json scripts for mistakes. An improper path or file name might result in the module not being found.
5. Node Version Compatibility.
   Although Node.js version 21.5.0 should function with the majority of packages, including Tailwind CSS, there may be compatibility concerns. If feasible, search for compatibility comments in the Tailwind CSS manual or community conversations.
6. Directly run Tailwind CLI
   Try using the Tailwind CLI command directly in your terminal: npx tailwindcss -i./src/styles.css -o../static/css/dist/styles.css -w. This can assist determine whether the problem is limited to the Django integration or a larger setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I believe the problem is in providing ther full address to npm in settings.py in windows.  I re loaded the files in different machine using pycharm.
In settings.py I put NPM_BIN_PATH = "npm.cmd" and everything worked as expected.